# QT 5.8 Removing margins from QGroupBox not working

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

So i have a `QGroupBox` with a vertical layout inside of it.
There is a `QWidget` container at top(blue).

I have used `setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)` for both the `QGroupBox` and the `QWidget` container yet no matter what i do i cannot get the `QWidget` container to be at **(0,0)** in the top left of the groupbox.  Ive marked in red the spacing i want to remove.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You must algo set the margins of the layout to 0. Given a widget -- either your `QGroupBox` or your `QWidget` -- you can use the `layout()` method to access its underlying layout, and then set the margins on it. Something like this:

```
widget->layout()->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Those are `QLayout` margins. Set them to zero.